# Why this result in MySQL is different than Excel or Calc?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I've been very confused because this calculation gives different results.

```
Select (10/110*48576000)
```

The result is:  4415999.9558

But if I do it in Excel using `= 10/110*48576000` the result is `4416000`. Even if you count it in Calc, 10 divide by 110 and multiply by 48576000, the result is `4416000`.

Can someone explain me this weird behaviour?

Note I'm using Mysql 5.5.46 in Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to MySQL converting calculations to float which is at best an approximation of a number.  If you round the solution then 4415999.9558 rounded to 0 decimal places is 4416000.

In MS SQL the calculation results in 0 because the result is an integer and the steps are

```
10 /110 = 0
0 * 48576000 = 0
```

however

```
Select 1.0 * 10 /110 *48576000
4415995.584000
```

If you are explicit about the data types you get the correct answer i.e.

```
declare @a  decimal(18,10) = 10;
declare @b  decimal(18,10) = 110;
declare @c  decimal(18,10) = 48576000;
select @a /@b *@c
4416000.00000000000
```

Comment: PostgreSQL returns 0, too.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL datatype `FLOAT` has only about 7 significant digits of precision.  That's the precision you got.  `DOUBLE` has about 16.  `DECIMAL` has a variable amount of precision, but has some possibly-strange rules when a divide is involved.

Excel uses a different set of rules than MySQL.

Bottom line:  Do not expect the 'right' answer when using lots of digits and/or using division or transcendental functions.